# Print the values of a model in a form and edit them Django

Tags: python, django, forms, models, display

Started of learning Django python a week or two ago, so please keep this in mind.

What I want is for data to be displayed in forms and it will be edited with in the same forms, for example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyXCP.png)

Where it says:
First Name
Last Name
email

I would like it to pull the data from the database and have it written out inside of forms.

First Name Kevin
Last Name Clark
email Kevin.clark@gmail.com

and so on for each entry.
Like it is written down bellow where it says you created these.
So one editing form with values written out for each set of entry's.

I hope that I have managed to pose a clear question and I do not believe to the best of my knowledge that it is a duplicate, if it is I am so sorry.

OS:Fedora
IDE:Eclipse
Django Python

views.py

```
def edit(request):
    instance = New.objects.all()
    data = { "firstName" : "Clark",
                  "lastName": "Kevin"}
    form = NewForm(request.POST) #instance=instance)
    print form.instance.firstName

    if(form.is_valid()):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()

    context = {
               "object_list" : instance,
               "formset" : form,
               "instance" : instance
    }

    return render(request, "secondTry/new.html", context)
```

models.py

```
class New(models.Model):
firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
email = models.EmailField()
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
```

forms.py

```
class NewForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = New
    fields = [
              "firstName", 
              "lastName", 
              "email"
              ]
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Create a New One</h1>
            <form method='post' action=""> {% csrf_token %}
                <table>
                    {{ formset }}
                </table>
                <input type='submit' value="Submit">
            </form>

            {{ instance }} {% csrf_token %}

            <h2>You Created These</h2>
            {% for obj in object_list %}
                    {{ obj.firstName }} 
                    {{ obj.lastName }} 
                    {{ obj.email }} <br/><br/>
                {% endfor %}






    </body>
</html>
```

Note, I am not using all the variables in def edit as I am going back and forth trying to figure this out so it might be a bit messy.

Thank you all so much for your time.

Comment: Also if you could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you just want the initial values to show up in the form? In that case you're looking for https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values

When you're creating an instance of your `Form`, do something like `name_form = Form(request.POST, initial=db_instance)`
Assuming that your edit view is already loading the instance from the DB somehow.

Comment: It still does not print it within the form: instance = New.objects.get(id=1) form = NewForm(request.POST, instance=instance)

Comment: But am reading the documentation and trying to apply it to this case.

Comment: This seams to be working to an extent  instance = New.objects.get(id=1)
        data = { "firstName" : "Clark",
                      "lastName": "Kevin"}
        form = NewForm(data, instance=instance)#request.POST

Comment: But I would like it to show each instance so create one form per an instance.

Comment: In that case you're looking for https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: Thank you so much, I managed to solve the problem with the info you gave me.